# Parse XML tag to boolean if it exists when unmarshalling

Tags: xml, go, unmarshalling

I'm trying to parse XML tag into a boolean if it exists. The tags inside `<status>` can be `<active />`, `<available />` or `<invalid />` and only one of these tag exists inside `<status>`.

Here's my current attempt:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

type Response struct {
    XMLName      xml.Name `xml:"domain"`
    Authority    string   `xml:"authority,attr"`
    RegistryType string   `xml:"registryType,attr"`
    EntityClass  string   `xml:"entityClass,attr"`
    EntityName   string   `xml:"entityName,attr"`
    DomainName   string   `xml:"domainName"`
    Status       Status   `xml:"status"`
}

type Status struct {
    Active    bool `xml:"active,omitempty"`
    Available bool `xml:"available,omitempty"`
    Invalid   bool `xml:"invalid,omitempty"`
}

func main() {

    str := `
<domain authority="domain.fi" registryType="dchk1" entityClass="domain-name" entityName="esimerkki.fi">
  <domainName>esimerkki.fi</domainName>
  <status>
    <active />
  </status>
</domain>
`

    var ans Response
    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &ans)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf(`%#v`, ans.Status)
}
```

This returns all `Status.*` as `false` and not `Status.Active = true` as expected. How can you get the expected result?

Second attempt with pointers:

```
type Status struct {
    Active    *bool `xml:"active,omitempty"`
    Available *bool `xml:"available,omitempty"`
    Invalid   *bool `xml:"invalid,omitempty"`
}
```

`*ans.Status.Active` still `false`.

Comment: Have you tried to set Active property to `*bool` ? If that works, then you have to check for nil / non nil pointer and not the boolean value.

Comment: @mh-cbon  Now I have and didn't work. Also added this to question.

Comment: i think we misunderstood. In that play, https://play.golang.org/p/9ARvyErrQ8A , when the tag is present the property will be set to its zero value (nil bool with a value of false). When the tag is not present, the property is set to nil, meaning the tag is not present. I don t think you can get Status.Active = true, unless you implement a special unmarshaler type, but you can detect presence/absence given nil / not nil properties.

Comment: @mh-cbon Got it, and answered :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @mh-cbon suggested simply checking for if pointer wasn't `nil` for `*bool` was enough to determine if that tag existed. But I went and turned the XML response struct into proper `Response` struct which only contains needed information and `Status` into a constant.

So now it's:

```
// Raw XML DTO
type XmlResponse struct {
    XMLName      xml.Name  `xml:"domain"`
    Authority    string    `xml:"authority,attr"`
    RegistryType string    `xml:"registryType,attr"`
    EntityClass  string    `xml:"entityClass,attr"`
    EntityName   string    `xml:"entityName,attr"`
    DomainName   string    `xml:"domainName"`
    Status       XmlStatus `xml:"status"`
}

// Raw XML DTO
type XmlStatus struct {
    Active    *bool `xml:"active,omitempty"`
    Available *bool `xml:"available,omitempty"`
    Invalid   *bool `xml:"invalid,omitempty"`
}

// Return Response struct which doesn't have the unnecessary XML
func (x XmlResponse) GetResponse() Response {
    st := Invalid // Default to invalid

    if x.Status.Active != nil {
        st = Active
    } else if x.Status.Available != nil {
        st = Available
    } else if x.Status.Invalid != nil {
        st = Invalid
    }

    return Response{
        Domain: x.DomainName,
        Status: st,
    }
}

// Proper response parsed from XML
type Response struct {
    Domain string
    Status Status
}

type Status uint8

const (
    Invalid Status = iota
    Active
    Available
)
```

And parsing happens as:

```
var xmlresp XmlResponse
err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &xmlresp)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

ans := xmlresp.GetResponse()

fmt.Printf(`%#v`, ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect solution, but this a quick and dirty hack. You can create structs for each item.

```
type XmlStatus struct {
    Active    Active     `xml:"active,omitempty"`
    Available Available  `xml:"available,omitempty"`
    Invalid   Invalid    `xml:"invalid,omitempty"`
}

type Active struct {
   XMLName xml.Name
}

type Available struct {
    XMLName xml.Name
}

type Invalid struct {
    XMLName xml.Name 
}
```

Then in your later code each answer will have a field under it called XMLName and that will have a field called local. It will contain the local xmlname. You can check that field with a simple if statement. i.e.

```
if ans.State.Active.XMLName.Local != "" {
    // user is active 
}
```

Kinda clunky hack, but it is simple and works.